# How to change docker user settings and entrypoint which already assigned to run a container

Tags: security, docker, containers, settings

I use Docker 1.12.3

I want to pull an image, which created for a particular user, says odoo, the image already composed to run as "odoo" user.
Now I want to make some change to the volume, I have to run 
      apt install vim 
on them to get it done, then I have to run the image with
      docker run --user=root  -i -t --entrypoint /bin/bash odoo:9.0

How can I get back the container to run as "odoo" and default entrypoint as it already composed?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own Dockerfile and in this file you will have to specify:

```
FROM odoo:9.0
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install x y z
```

Doing so wouldn't change the ENTRYPOINT as long as you don't specify one.